# Official documentation of Surface hardware

Tags: pixelsense

I'm looking for an official documentation of the hardware used by Microsoft Surface 1.0. I found the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface), but there aren't really official references for the facts mentioned.

Any hints where to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692114(Surface.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks that looks great! Do you also know a resource where I can find an image where the projectors etc are described?

Comment: http://www.cheaplaptops.org.uk/20070601/microsoft-surface-diagram-how-it-all-works/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the official Microsoft Surface Table Data Sheet (pdf):
http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9686793

And this is an article by Geoff Walker and Mark Fihn about the touch technology inside of the Surface Table (pdf):
http://www.walkermobile.com/March_2010_ID_Beneath_the_Surface.pdf